# How do I unmap a project?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

How do I unmap a project in Team Foundation Server 2010?

I changed the location of a source control, and completely removed it from TFS source control. but now it is showing up wanting to add it:

[image]

Also, when I try to Map the new project, it is giving the error below. I've completely deleted the files off my local PC, and I'm wanting to map and get latest version from source control, but it gives an error trying to map. I'd rather not change the location. How do I remove the old binding and the project, when it was already deleted using `TfsDeleteProject.exe`?

[image]

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You should be able to go to **Workspaces** and remove/add any mappings there directly.

1. Go To **Source Control Explorer**
2. Expand the **Workspaces drop-down** along the toolbar in the Source Control Explorer
3. Click the **last entry** to manage workspaces

There you should be able to remove mappings.

Here is an article discussing Workspaces
http://www.woodwardweb.com/teamprise/000334.html

Comment: Thanks, that helped with the binding.. still getting my old source control trying to add though... any ideas?

Comment: Whoa! I found out that a second "working folder" had accidently been created in the middle of my folder hierarchy and that's why TFS was acting really weird (like - folder already mapped to server). I wonder why that happens.....

Comment: But...what to do after step 3? I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and it's not obvious.

Comment: I've removed the workspace, using this advice, but I can't add a mapping because there's already a mapping with the same path. Even though i've got no workspaces at all. I restart visual studio 2010 and the workspace re-appears.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add something to the accepted response...

If you have used some other credential to get code previously, then there would be a workspace already existing that would be mapped to the mentioned local folder. In that case the new credential can not be used to map the same server folder to the same local folder. You will first have to login with the older credential and delete that workspace and then you need to create a new workspace with your new ID and then map to the desired folder (which should now be unlocked) and you should be ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

In the source Control Explorer right click on the solution you would like to Remove Mapping [**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkvHL.png.)

Click "Remove Mapping"